# How to shade the intersection portion? using tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

### How to shade the intersection portion?

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmax=9,ymax=9, samples=50]
  \addplot[blue, ultra thick] (x,x*x);
  \addplot[red,  ultra thick] (x*x,x);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output:

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the `fillbetween` pgfplots library.

Comment: @HenriMenke though this would be my choice as well, it does not really work for this example. There are the wrong segements colored and even setting `reverse=true` does not give the correct result. Maybe you want to provide an answer or try as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using `intersection segments`. It needs the pgfplots library `fillbetween`.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmax=9,ymax=9, samples=50,set layers]
  \addplot[name path=plot 1,blue, ultra thick] (x,x*x);
  \addplot[name path=plot 2, red,  ultra thick] (x*x,x);
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{axis tick labels}
  \fill[green,
    intersection segments={
      of=plot 1 and plot 2,
      sequence={L2--R2[reverse]}
    }];
  \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much... will it work if I have more than two curves?? any reference links??